# Use WAR as dependency in Maven

Tags: maven, war

I was given a project by a client that has a bunch of dependencies that are in a WAR file that they provided. I have added the dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oragle.oipa</groupId>
        <artifactId>PASJava</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.25</version>
        <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

But clearly, as I physically have the files, they cannot be installed by Maven automatically. What can I do to get Maven to recognize their location and set them up for me?

Comment: Two upvotes in one hour in the weekend?  And this is not java-se or jsf related!

Answer (score 0):

If the war is not associated to a pom.xml, you should "mavenize" it to be able to use is as a Maven dependency in another Maven project.

1) You can look the `install-file` goal of the Maven install plugin.
It allow to generate and deploy the pom  in your local repository.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

With your example, you could generate and install the war artifact in this way:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=locationOfYourWarFile -DgroupId=com.oragle.oipa
    -DartifactId=PASJava -Dversion=10.2.0.25 -Dpackaging=war
```

2) You can also look at the `deploy-file` goal of the Maven deploy plugin.
It allows to generate and deploy the pom in a remote repository. It may be useful if other users need the war as a Maven dependency.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

Here is an example from documentation :

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file://C:\m2-repo \
                       -DrepositoryId=some.id \
                       -Dfile=your-artifact-1.0.jar \
                       [-DpomFile=your-pom.xml] \
                       [-DgroupId=org.some.group] \
                       [-DartifactId=your-artifact] \
                       [-Dversion=1.0] \
                       [-Dpackaging=jar] \
                       [-Dclassifier=test] \
                       [-DgeneratePom=true] \
                       [-DgeneratePom.description="My Project Description"] \
                       [-DrepositoryLayout=legacy] \
                       [-DuniqueVersion=false]
```